# Delete method on same view namespaced Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a namespace on my application for an admin system:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :activities
  get 'dashboard', to: 'backend#index'
end
```

The Sign In devise method is the /admin of my application, redirected to my dashboard

```
/admin/dashboard => get 'dashboard', to: 'backend#index'
```

I have a CRUD: Activities, I can edit and create activities and it redirecting good on my dashboard where the activity table is.
In this table I also have a delete link, but it's not working. I think it's cause i redirecting on /admin/dashboard and i'm already on it ....

My links are:

```
%td= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_activity_path(activity)
%td= link_to 'Destroy', admin_dashboard_path, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```

I got the error:

> No route matches [DELETE] "/admin/dashboard"

If I put:

```
%td= link_to 'Destroy', admin_dashboard_path(activity), :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```

I got the url:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/admin/dashboard.1"
```

And my controller:

```
def destroy
  @activity.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to admin_dashboard_path}
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Can someone help me with this problem please?

Thanks by advance

Comment: you don't have a DELETE route for admin_dashboard? do you mean to delete admin_activity?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use the resource delete of the activities, do I need to create a route for the dashboard too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your link_to should be in order to link to the destroy action on activities controller.

```
%td= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_activity_path(activity)
%td= link_to 'Destroy', admin_activity_path(activity), :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```